# Retrieve all values in form:select in JSP page with spring tag

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a form with two multiselect dropdowns, 
using java script i am moving value from one dropdown select to otherwhen button is clicked and mvoing from seconf to first dropdown select when another button is clicked.

Whn i submit the form i want to get all values in form:select (ie., values which are nor selected by user are also to be retrieved)

The jsp is as folllows:

```
                <form:form id="adduser" commandName="Bean" action="add.htm" method="post">

                                        <form:select id="availableOptions" path="availableOptions" name="availableOptions" multiple="multiple" size="9" style="width:6em" onblur="hide();">
                                            <c:forEach items="${Bean.availableOptions}" var="name">
                                                <option>${name}</option>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        </form:select>
                                        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="movefromAvailabletoSelected();"></input>
                                        <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="movefromSelectedtoAvailable();"></input>
                                        <form:select id="selectedOptions" path="selectedOptions" name="selectedOptions" multiple="multiple" size="9" style="width:6em">
                                            <c:forEach items="${Bean.selectedOptions}" var="name">
                                                <option>${name}</option>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        </form:select>

                            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit"  style="margin-left: 15%"/>
            </form:form>
```

Comment: You can set the values in `List` in your controller and forward it to the JSP

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do it directly in a select, but there are some indirect options:

**1. change the select to a multi-select and use javascript to select all values on submit**

In this method you would set the select like:

```
<form:select multiple="true path="mySelect">
   ...
```

Then, if we were say using jQuery we could do something like:

```
$("#myForm).submit(function() {
  $('#mySelect option').attr('checked','checked');
});
```

This was written off-the-cuff and has not been tested, and it doesn't necessarily HAVE to use jQuery, but it shows the general idea.  Another option would be to maintain a hidden field that is a delimited list of the values in the select, again using some sort of JavaScript.

**2. Have some sort of AJAX call every time the button is pressed**

This would take a whole lot more architecturally to accomplish, but the idea would be to set up an AJAX call to move the values from one to the other on the back-end.  This way the UI and the backend would stay in-sync.  There are lots of considerations with this approach, like do you operate on a "temporary" model so that you don't modify the original until they do the final submit, in which case you then copy the temp over?

I am sure there are others, but it's early and my brain hasn't fully engaged yet.